# How can I fix my login problem?

Tags: login

I recently attempted to fix an issue with my battery indicator by uninstalling and reinstalling u-power-indicator. After restarting my laptop to see if the issue was fixed ubuntu but the login tells me that it "Failed to start session" and wouldn't let me log in. I've tried changing my password with recovery mode but I still cant seem to log in. Logging in through ctrl-alt-f1 with the new password works, it's just through the graphical login that won't work. Any suggestions?

update:

```
ls -al /home/kjfs/.*authority*
```

```
-rw------- 1 kjfs kjfs 8694 Jan 12 14:47 /home/kjfs/.ICEauthority
-rw------- 1 kjfs kjfs   52 Jan 12 14:47 /home/kjfs/.XauthorityBak
```

Comment: What did you do exactly prior to that event?

Comment: Can you also be more specific than *"tried fixing it in recovery mode"* - what steps did you take, exactly?

Comment: Log into ctrl-alt-f1 and type `ls -al /home/put_your_username_here/.*authority*` and edit your question to include that output. Put `@heynnema` in front of comments directed to me, or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema my two outputs: -rw------- 1 kjfs kjfs 8694 Jan 12 14:47 /home/kjfs/.ICEauthority and  -rw------- 1 kjfs kjfs 52 Jan 12 14:47 /home/kjfs/.XauthorityBak

Comment: type `sudo mv /home/kjfs/.XauthorityBak /home/kjfs/.Xauthority` then do the previous `ls -al` command and make sure it says "kjfs kjfs" (not "root root") for each filename, like it does now. Then type `reboot` and see if you can log in.

Comment: Edit your question to include the output of `df -h` and `ls -al /home` and `dpkg -l lightdm | grep lightdm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have deleted your workspace what you should do is to reinstall your graphical interface. For example:

```
apt-get install gnome2
```

Or:

```
apt-get install lightdm
```

Or:

```
apt-get install xfce4
```

Comment: If a package -- e.g., `xfce4` -- is already installed, running `apt-get install xfce4` won't reinstall it. `apt-get` sees the package is installed and won't install anything. (It marks the package as manually installed rather than automatically installed, if it's not already marked that way, but this doesn't do anything to any of the package's files.) To reinstall a package, you have to use the `--reinstall` flag. If it's possible conffiles may be damaged or wrong, and the package's current configuration needn't be retained, use `--purge` too. So: `apt-get --purge --reinstall install xfce4`.

Answer (score 0):

- Press

  ```
  CTRL+ALT+F1
  ```
- Log in with you user name and password
- Run the following command:

  ```
  sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME
  ```
- Press CTRL+ALT+F7
- Try to log in
  OR go back to "purely text window" and try deleting

```
rm ~/.Xauthority
```